# What is 1UnHooker.sys?

Tags: windows-7, virus, malware, rootkit

I'm still searching for a solution to my problem as I stated in my previous question ([UAC being turned off every time Windows 7 starts (once a day)](https://superuser.com/questions/234168/uac-being-turned-off-every-time-windows-7-starts-once-a-day)). Today, a program called SpyHunter found an unknown object on my computer. The name of the file is **`1UnHooker.sys`** and it is located in `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\`. It has also a registry entry.

[image: 1UnHooker.sys screeny]

Googling this name did not help much. Is it a rootkit or malware? Should I delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VirusTotal](http://www.virustotal.com/file-scan/report.html?id=c8c5ed6ca8a8df49f0deb8a093fd85dfba2a68434c9c7d739d191c4bc5b103ba-1286295761) only has McAfee-GW-Edition say `Heuristic.BehavesLike.Win32.Rootkit.H`.

Looking into [this](http://www.threatexpert.com/report.aspx?md5=78dda9fa7e7d3cf9cf758755d2e39474) further, it seems to be **Tizerï¿½ Rootkit Razor** and that file is Tizer File System Driver.

All that is hidden under the name X-Wire Technology and a fake service called Windows Installer.

Comment: I used Tizer Rootkit Razor last week, then I uninstalled it. That program should have left it. I just found [this](http://download.cnet.com/Tizer-Rootkit-Razor/9241-2239_4-11308031.html?messageID=10597962&tag=uo;uo), so I shouldn't have trusted that program. Thanks.

Comment: I deleted it together with the registry leftovers with no remorse.