# UAC settings are automatically disabled at least once a day

Tags: windows, security, uac

I have a weird security risk that I have submitted to our IT Operations without any luck; at least once a day, our machines running Windows 7, 8.1 and 10 has the UAC settings disabled, and we discover this by the balloon asking us to restart so the changes may apply.

[image]

When I see this message, I go to Action Center and enable the UAC on the recommended level again.

I suspect this to be a rule by the aforementioned IT Operations, because all machines are affected. I have not been successful in achieving an answer from them.

Before suggesting malware etc. - this has been firmly checked for.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I am curious WHY it's happening AND annoyed/puzzled why anyone would lower the security in terms of "comfort" for our "normal" users.

---

1st edit: this is how the local policy looks; I doubt any of these settings defaults the UAC to "Never Notify" randomly.

[image]

---

2nd edit: This link, [UAC being turned off once a day on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/234168/uac-being-turned-off-once-a-day-on-windows-7), looks similar to my issue, and I have for the time being changed UAC to the highest levels as I suspect our IT Operations to have a Domain script that disables the UAC. Why anynone would do this still remains a mystery.

Comment: Verify it is the group policy, if you are an Administrator, this should be easy enough.  If it is the group policy and you don't have access, you will have to find somebody who can change it, because even being a local administrator cannot and will not overrule a group policy.

Comment: Do you know what to look for en Group / Local policy? I don't know the setting that would allow this behavior. Also, I am only local Administrator .. and to my knowledge, Group Policy (Domain Policy?) is controlled through the DC, right?

Comment: To get a list of which domain policies are affecting your user and the computer use something like `GPResult /h c:\temp\results.html` (run it from a command-prompt opened "as administrator")